# Adding a :focus border to a text input, and getting rid of the default one

Tags: html, css, forms, border

In css, I want to have a 2 pixel light blue border when a given textbox is in focus. I have the following:

```
form input.text:focus
{
border:2px solid #09F;
}
```

Pretty simple. The problem is, the default orange border can still be seen outside of my new blue one. How can I get rid of this?

Comment: This is a duplicate I believe to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671811/howto-hide-outline-on-a-form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure it pertains to the `outline` property as it's usually blue, not orange (which browser are you on?). Anyway, try simply adding  `outline: none;` to that ruleset.